# Raised Bed Cover Crops - Zone 6

Tags: raised-beds, cover-crop

I have 4 new raised beds I built this year.  They were filled quite deep with what was supposed to be pretty good soil (turns out I was duped, just like you read often online!) - it's largely all topsoil and uncomposted manure.  Regardless of this season - which I'm getting mild growth out of due to a lot of added compost, I am already making soil repair plans w/ cover crops.

I am looking for a crop or mix that will:

- Add Nitrogen to the soil and a lot of organic material
- Is an annual, not a perennial - I want no risk here =)
- Can be seeded in the beds sometime between September and November in Zone 6 (Ohio)
- Is easy to till back into bed in spring

I am thinking about [Winter Rye](https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/B01KTX5NIG) - although I understand it does not provide nitrogen into the soil but likely meets my other needs.  Also considering [Alfalfa](https://smile.amazon.com/Non-GMO-Alfalfa-Seeds-Germination-Conventional/dp/B07G69Z8B9) (although I can't find organic seeds yet), or [Hairy Vetch](https://smile.amazon.com/Davids-Garden-Seeds-Hairy-Vetch-Organic/dp/B00SRWMJ9S).  Some farms have [cover crop mixes](https://www.walnutcreekseeds.com/Gardening-Mixes.html) too, not sure if that's a good idea for raised beds where I can't really use machines to till back in?

There is a lot of scattered info online and most are geared toward serious farmers, so hopefully some folks here can lead me in the right direction!

Comment: Note that alfalfa is a perennial.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that if there's uncomposted manure in the soil you've probably got enough nitrogen, it just needs to break down. Have a look at [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/13810/does-it-make-sense-to-plant-a-cover-crop-in-raised-beds?rq=1). If it were me, I'd go with Winter Rye if I were determined to use a cover crop. It will hold the nitrogen that is there. Adding compost instead might be more efficient. Manually turning a cover crop seems like a lot of work.